# MSBuild - copy files based on platform

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have some native dlls that come in 2 flavors - built for x86 and x64. Based on my project platform configuration, I would like to copy the right dlls into the folder.

What I tried

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_nativex86 Include="native\myNativex86folder\*.*" />
    <_nativex64 Include="native\myNativex64folder\*.*  />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy Condition="$(Platform) == x86"
        SourceFiles = "$(_nativex86)"
        DestinationFolder = "$(OutputPath)native" />
    <Copy Condition="$(Platform) == x64"
        SourceFiles = "$(_nativex64)"
        DestinationFolder = "$(OutputPath)native" />
</Target>
```

However, nothing gets copied. What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_nativex86 Include="native\myNativex86folder\*.*" />
    <_nativex64 Include="native\myNativex64folder\*.*  />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' "
        SourceFiles = "$(_nativex86)"
        DestinationFolder = "$(TargetDir)native" />
    <Copy Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' "
        SourceFiles = "$(_nativex64)"
        DestinationFolder = "$(TargetDir)native" />
</Target>
```

I added quotes for values in the `Condition`s.

You can try also prepend "native" paths with `$(SolutionDir)` (*or `$(ProjectDir)`, `$(OutputPath)` etc depending on where the files are located*) to make them full paths.